# Themes and icons change to default automatically in Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: unity, themes, icons, customization

I have customized my ubuntu themes and icons but after rebooting the computer
I find my themes and icons change to default.

I tried to solve it by starting recovery mode to fix the damaged package.I got my themes and my icons back  but after rebooting the problem appears again.

I think there is problem with gnome and unity.

that's how my desktop appears 
[image: http://s16.postimg.org/yguwh0fdx/Screenshot_from_2014_04_20_09_13_50.png]
and that's how my normal desktop appears

[image: http://s16.postimg.org/4xverr5d1/Screenshot_from_2014_04_20_09_18_05.png]
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32-Bit

Comment: To me, both the images look same.

Comment: @PatilAditya i agree

Comment: he just removed the other picture
If u can't help don't be noobie about it

Comment: are u use MacBuntu ?